# C++ code compiles in CentOS g++, but not in Visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, windows, linux, visual-c++, encoding

I have a problem: My codes work well in CentOS g++, but when I compile them in visual studio 2008, the visual studio tells me errors like below:

> 1.c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(19) : error C2144: syntax error : '__w64 unsigned int' should be preceded by '}'
>
> 2.error C2143: syntax error : missing '}' before 'namespace'.

My file coding is UTF-8. Should I change them in Unicode all, I change some error file in Unicode,it still has errors like above.

below are some sourecode:

```
#ifndef ENRC_CODE_DEFS_H
#define ENRC_CODE_DEFS_H

enum ENReturnCode
{
ENRC_SUCCESS = 0,
ENRC_FAILED,
ENRC_NODATA,
ENRC_CONFIG_NOT_AVAILABLE,
ENRC_INVALID_SUBSCRIBE_ID,
ENRC_INVALID_SUBSCRIBE_CONDITION,
ENRC_INVALID_SUBSCRIBER,
ENRC_INVALID_PARAMETER,
ENRC_THREAD_RUNNING,
ENRC_SUBSCRIBE_LIST_EMPTY,
ENRC_OUT_OF_MEMORY     // 10
}
```

`e:\my_code\cppcommon\include\errordefs.h(5) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'enum [tag]'`

next:

```
#ifndef EN_SMS_SRC_TAO2CPP_H_        
#define EN_SMS_SRC_TAO2CPP_H_
#include "SystemMonitorMasterServiceC.h"
#include "SystemMonitorSlaveServiceC.h"
#include "CommonDefs.h"
#include "SystemMonitorServiceDataDefs.h"

namespace EN
{
namespace SMS
{
template < typename _Ty, typename _Cy>
inline
void Tao2Cpp_Enum(_Ty taoValue, _Cy &cppValue)
{
   cppValue = (_Cy)taoValue;
}
```

`error C2143: syntax error : missing '}' before 'namespace'`

A lot of errors like above.

Thanks. I waste some time to make it easy to read.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you if you don't post the source?

Comment: Please format your code properly and please show us the part of your source code which contains the lines on which the error occurs. Do not worry, we will not steal your industrial secrets.

Comment: @JonEgerton your edit undid some changes I did in the title; was that intentional, or was it an unfortunate result of merging?

Comment: @MikeNakis: Must have been the merge

Comment: for me it compiles on VS2005 and g++ 4.1.2 and 4.4 under centos, of course after adding few ending brackets/semicolons...

Comment: yes,I convert them to Unicode,the errors are disappear,I think the point is ending marks.I include the file is UTF-8,vs thinks it not ending,so it tell me that errors.thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You need a semi-colon in the enum declaration:

```
enum ENReturnCode 
{
...
};
```

Comment: sorry,the enum is evry large,It has ';'in the end,I forget take it here.

Comment: The encoding cause the problem,In windows,the sourcecode file's encoding is gbk, in linux is utf-8.The window's sourcecode file's have Chinese word in comment and the CL/RF is broken in these files.For example, The comment is "//谢谢你", you must add a space behind the comment, everything is going well.At the end,my English is so poor.^_^.